# How to do group of this equations?

Tags: equations, diagrams

Here (P1) denotes problem 1 and (P2) denotes problem 2. (D1) and (D2) denotes their relaxations. I want to pose the question whether the relaxations may or may not be equal. I am familiar with writing the individual problems in latex. While I am not sure how to align them to do whatever is written in the paper. This is a crude form of what I want to achieve?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You really should put some effort into showing us what you have tried to this point, if you are hoping for free help.  That said...

Here, I use stack nesting to accomplish the result.  By saving the corners into their own `\normalsize` stack boxes (`\Pone`, `\Ptwo`, `\Rone`, and `\Rtwo`), I can then build the overall tabbed-stack in any fontsize I wish (here I chose `\LARGE`, and it won't affect the fonts in the prior saved stack boxes, but only the connective symbols between them.

The various stackgaps set in the preamble affect the horizontal gap between columns (`\setstacktabbedgap`), the default vertical gap of short stacks (`\setstackgap{S}{}`, for `\tabbedShortstack` and `\stackon`), and the default vertical baselineskip of long stacks (`\setstackgap{L}{}`, for `\Centerstack`), respectively.

I also demonstrate (in the EDITED version) how I set `\stackMath` to process the corner boxes in math mode, and then revert to `\stackText` to process the overall tabbed arrangement in text mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstacktabbedgap{3ex}
\setstackgap{S}{3ex}
\setstackgap{L}{1.7\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\stackMath
\savestack{\Pone}{\Centerstack{
  \fbox{P1}\\\displaystyle\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}} f_1(x)\\g_1(x)==C_1}
}
\savestack{\Ptwo}{\Centerstack{
  \fbox{P2}\\\displaystyle\min_{y\in\mathbb{R}} f_2(x)\\g_2(x)==C_2}
}
\savestack{\Rone}{\Centerstack{
  \fbox{R1}\\\displaystyle\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}} f_{R_1}(x)\\g_{R_1}(x)==C_{R_1}}
}
\savestack{\Rtwo}{\Centerstack{
  \fbox{R2}\\\displaystyle\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}} f_{R_2}(x)\\g_{R_2}(x)==C_{R_2}}
}
\stackText
{\LARGE\tabbedShortstack{
 \Pone & \stackon[.6ex]{$\equiv$}{theorem 1} & \Ptwo\\
  \llap{Relax~}$\Downarrow$ & & $\Downarrow$\rlap{~Relax}\\
 \Rone & \stackon[.6ex]{$\equiv$}{?} & \Rtwo\\
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With a default `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{concrete}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\begin{document}

\def\arraystretch{2.5}
\begin{tabular}{*3{>{\Centering}m{3cm}}}
  \fbox{P1}\newline$\min\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}} f_1(x)$\newline$g_1(x)==C_1$ & 
  \Large theorem 1 \newline $\equiv$ &
  \fbox{P2}\newline$\min\limits_{y\in\mathbb{R}} f_2(x)$\newline$g_2(x)==C_2$ \\
  \Large\strut Relax $\Downarrow$ &  \Large\strut   & \Large\strut $\Downarrow$ Relax\\
  \fbox{R1}\newline$\min\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}} f_{R_1}(x)$\newline$g_{R_1}(x)==C_{R_1}$ &
  \huge? \newline $\equiv$ &
  \fbox{R2}\newline$\min\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}} f_{R_2}(x)$\newline$g_{R_2}(x)==C_{R_2}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative using `tikz-cd` and `array` environment

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
\begin{array}{c}
(P1)\\
\displaystyle\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f_1(x)\\
g_1(x)==C_1
\end{array} 
\arrow[Rightarrow]{d}[swap]{Relax}         
& 
\begin{array}{c}
\textbf{Theorem 1}\\
\equiv
\end{array} 
& 
\begin{array}{c}
(P2)\\
\displaystyle \min_{y \in \mathbb{R}} f_2(x)\\
g_2(x)==C_2\\
\end{array}
\arrow[Rightarrow]{d}{Relax}      
&
&\\
\begin{array}{c}
(R1)\\
\displaystyle\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f_{R_1}(x)\\
g_{R_1}(x)==C_{R_1} 
\end{array}  
& 
\begin{array}{c}
? \\ 
\equiv
\end{array}
&  
\begin{array}{c}
(R2)\\
\displaystyle\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f_{R_2}(x)\\
g_{R_2}(x)==C_{R_2}
\end{array}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do i put circle around $P1$ instead of parantheses

Comment: Define this in the preamble \usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}} Then use  $\circled{P1}$ in the corresponding locations.